# VBA - Loop through worksheets to find max value in user-selected range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, input, worksheet

I'm trying to find the maximum value for each worksheet in my workbook that is dependent on a user-selected range. I want the user to select a range just once and find the max for each worksheet based on that range.

In other words, say the user selects the range B1:B100. The macro should loop through each sheet and find the max value in each sheet's B1:B100 range.

Ultimately, each worksheet has a set of data points that I want to divide by the max value found in the user-selected range.

Here is my code (well, the relevant parts):

```
Sub Plot()

Dim i, ws_count As Integer
Dim userng, brng As Range
Dim maxval As Double

On Error GoTo Canceled

Set userng = Excel.Application.InputBox("Please input range.", "Input", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

  For i = 1 To ws_count

    Worksheets(i).Activate

    maxval = userng.Cells(1, 1).Value
      For Each Cell In userng.Cells
        If Cell.Value > maxval Then
          maxval= Cell.Value
        End If
      Next Cell

    Set brng = Worksheets(i).Range("B1:B1869") ''brng will always be B1:B1869 for each worksheet

'Each cell in B1:B1869 should be divided by maxval.
      For Each Cell In brng
        Cell.Value = Cell.Value / maxval
      Next Cell

  Next i

Canceled:
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the macro only finds the max value for the first worksheet and applies this value to all the other worksheets. Ideally, each worksheet would be divided by its unique `maxval`.

I'd certainly appreciate any help that is given!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a user range directly from the user and then apply it as below:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Pls select range to examine (on all sheets)", "User Input", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 Debug.Print ws.Name, Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(rng1.Address))
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get the max value for the current range in each sheet:

```
Sub MaxInSheets()
    Dim MyRange As String, WS As Worksheet
    MyRange = Selection.Address
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        MsgBox WS.Name & " - " & WorksheetFunction.Max(WS.Range(MyRange))
    Next
    MsgBox MyMaxValue
End Sub
```

Post back if you need help to implement that into your own code.

I tried making MyRange a range but it didn't like it, I am not 100% sure but I think it may retain the sheet as a reference in the range? someone with more knowledge of the object will be able to confirm this though.